# Аргумент типа "WCHAR*" несовместим с параметром типа "const char*"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Всем привет. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]Сталкиваюсь с такой ошибкой:

аргумент типа "WCHAR *" несовместим с параметром типа "const char *"
Программа используется для проверки процессов и нахождения нужного (в моём случае notepad.exe) в реальном времени с обновлением каждую 1 секунду

```
char TargetProc[] = "notepad.exe";
bool ProcRabotaet = 0;
int ProcID;
//----------------------------------------------------------
HANDLE HandleProcessa() {
    HANDLE hProcessSnap;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32{};
    //Это мы находим дескриптор снимка процессов
    hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return false;
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    int i = 0;
    while (Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32)) {

        if (0 == strcmp(pe32.szExeFile, TargetProc))
        {
            ProcRabotaet = true;
            ProcID = pe32.th32ProcessID;
            return(0);
        }
        else  ProcRabotaet = false;
    }
    CloseHandle(hProcessSnap);
}
```

Comment: `wchar_t TargetProc[] = L"notepad.exe";` ; `strcmp` => `wcscmp(pe32.szExeFile, TargetProc)`

Comment: C2440
return: невозможно преобразовать "bool" в "HANDLE"
Теперь такая ошибка появилась

Comment: Ваш метод возвращает должен возвращать HANDLE, а вы в строках  `if (hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return false;` возвращаете bool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написал решение получше и проще, может кому пригодится:

```
bool IsProcessRun(const char* const ProcessName)
{
    HANDLE hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
    pe.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    Process32First(hSnapshot, &pe);

    while (1) {
        if (wcscmp(pe.szExeFile, L"notepad.exe") == 0) return true;
        if (!Process32Next(hSnapshot, &pe)) return false;
    }
}
```

Использование такое:

```
if (IsProcessRun("notepad.exe"))
            {
                cout << "True\n";

            }
            else
                cout << "False\n";
```